# Making Console User Interface in Python 3.4 for Linux and Windows

Tags: python, linux, windows, console-application

I'm writing the calculator, but first, I will try write console interface (to school). I don't know, what library I can use to write it (for both system). The interface will be look like this:
 - on top - simply menu
 - then some "window" for result of expression
 - the error "window"
 - and place where user will type the expression
I'm thinking about the line with some "radios" to change type of angle (but if it will be imposible - i insert it to menu).

Can someone help me? (If someone will give the link to good tutorial of library, I will be happy).

Answer (score 0):

For Linux Python comes with a curses library, but this isn't the case with Windows. Unfortunately there are no command line toolkits for Windows.

https://docs.python.org/2/howto/curses.html

Comment: If you're just using it for yourself, the python that comes in cygwin has the curses library but that's as far as it goes. That means you have to run it in the terminal program (mintty) it comes with.

Comment: For Windows you can try this [curses module](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#curses) that's based on [PDCurses](http://pdcurses.sourceforge.net).